# Voice / Speech recognition - PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, voice-recognition

Is there any plugin available to implement Voice recognition capability for PhoneGap app.

I came across ;

[Combine **Phono Mobile** with Tropo’s Cloud Communications API to create voice-enabled self-service applications which can include: speech recognition and text-to-speech in 24 languages, conferencing, call recording, voice transcription, and call transfers.](http://blog.phono.com/2011/07/22/introducing-phono-mobile/)

But the Tropo is a paid service, is there any open service available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My PhoneGap SpeechRec plugin for Android was just merged into the codebase.
If your requirements are Android-only, this should do the trick.

PhoneGap Plugin tree for Android:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android

Comment: Thank you, could you please mention the link

Comment: @koolspin, any plan to release this for iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ionic, it is possible to add a simple AngularJS directive and make it work:

[ng-speech-recognition](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)